# Inserting value in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I'm trying to give seconden(seconds) the start value 0 in my database. This happens when I insert a row, so the seconds are set to 0.

This is what I tried:

```
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Project.mdb";
        string SqlString = "Insert Into App (Naam, Site, Plaatje, Seconden) Values (?,?,?,0)";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Naam", Voernaamin.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Site", Voersitein.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Plaatje", Voerplaatjein.Text);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("Ingelogd2.aspx");
                }
            }
```

And also tried doing this: (also not working)

```
int nul = 0;
        string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Project.mdb";
        string SqlString = "Insert Into App (Naam, Site, Plaatje, Seconden) Values (?,?,?,?)";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Naam", Voernaamin.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Site", Voersitein.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Plaatje", Voerplaatjein.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Seconden", nul);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("Ingelogd2.aspx");
                }
            }
```

Can someone help me out so I can Seconden to 0? Its a numeric in the database itself btw.

Comment: What response does the DB give when these queries are run?

Comment: Can you give the error message that you get.

Comment: What is your `cmd` looks like when you add your parameter values? Is it works on database manager? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: Your query string looks pretty incorrect. What is supposed to be `Values (?,?,?,0)` ? You should insert parameters names there, like `(@Naam, @Site, @Plaatje, 0)`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev `OleDbCommand` doesn't support named parameters. Only matter is their orders.

Comment: @SonerGönül, oh missed the fact it was `OleDbCommand`. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error messages, the Seconden attribute is just empty. But I want 0 in it.

Comment: A general comment: [don't use AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
int nul = 0;
    string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Project.mdb";
    string SqlString = "Insert Into App (Naam, Site, Plaatje, Seconden) Values (@Naam,@Site,@Plaatje,@Seconden)";
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", Voernaamin.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site", Voersitein.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plaatje", Voerplaatjein.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seconden", "0");
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("Ingelogd2.aspx");
            }
        }
```